# Как заполнить приватный массив в другом классе через геттер/сеттер ? (используя Arrays.fill)

Tags: java, массивы

Подскажите пожалуйста, как заполнить приватный массив в другом классе через геттер/сеттер ? (используя Arrays.fill)
В одном классе массив и геттер/сеттер:

```
private int[] attempts = new int[10];

public int[] getAttempts() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(attempts, numberOfAttempt + 1);
}

public void setAttempt(int index, int number) {
    attempts[index] = number;
}
```

В другом классе нужно обнулить этот массив в части заполненных вариантов, используя Arrays.fill:

```
Arrays.fill(player1.getAttempts(), 0);
```

Данный вариант не обнуляет массив.

Если я делаю геттер следующим:

```
public int[] getAttempts() {
    return attempts;
}
```

то обнуление срабатывает.

Но как осуществить обнуление через первоначальные геттер/сеттер и возможно ли это ?

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Arrays.copyOf` как бы намекает, что возвращается копия оригинального массива, т.е. другая память, другая ссылка. Естественно, обнуление копии никак не повлияет на оригинальный массив. Можно сделать такой метод в вашем классе:

```
public void fill(int number) { 
    Arrays.fill(attempts , number); 
}
```

Ну либо возвращает ссылку на оригинальный массив.

Comment: т.е. при таких первоначальных геттерах я обращаюсь к копии и обнулить основной массив не получится ?  Предлагаемый вами метод добавить в класс рядом с геттером/сеттером ?  Но сюда я могу добавить и следующее:  //геттер для очистки массива
    public int[] getAttemptsZero() {
        return attempts;
    }  т.е. еще один геттер именно для очистки массива, но это лишний метод.

Comment: @Сергей да, именно так. По поводу геттера для очистки массива, то лучше тогда уж сделать getAttempts, который возвращает оригинальную ссылку и getAttemptsСopy, который возвращает копию, если вам так нужен метод с копированием

Comment: Спасибо, поэкспериментирую. Ну да, метод с копированием нужно оставить, но в этом случае получается, что все равно два метода нужно использовать - один для работы с оригиналом, второй для копии с ненулевыми вариантами. Это по сути, как я и создал изначально второй метод. Но это уже нагромождает код. Подумаю, еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @Сергей если ответ помог, то поставьте галочку